# Documentation has broken link (JSONP)

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

On Wikipedia, JSONP now has its own article, instead of being part of the JSON article.

The documentation links JSONP to Wikpedia:[JSON#JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP). It should link to Wikipedia:[JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

Comment: @Kevin: Since I noticed this was corrected in the latest API release, I've marked this as [status-complete]. Please rollback the changes if this is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this has now been fixed.